# yield memory issues in python

Tags: python, memory, generator, yield

I have a problem -> I want to yield information and put it into similar objects. But it seem that when I append the result to a list everything is pointing to the same address in memory, i suppose.

```py
def call(i):
    for j in range(i):
        yield j+1

def ring(i):
    obj = {}
    for j in call(i):
        obj['number'] = j
        yield obj
    
result = []
for k in ring(5):
    print(k) if k['number'] != 5 else print(k,'\n')
    result.append(k)

[print(x) for x in result]

# - OUTPUT -
#
#{'number': 1}
#{'number': 2}
#{'number': 3}
#{'number': 4}
#{'number': 5} 
#
#{'number': 5}
#{'number': 5}
#{'number': 5}
#{'number': 5}
#{'number': 5}
```

I think I see what is going on here. But I don't know how to get around it, I really need that list with the correct values.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: `ring` yields the same `obj` object every time; not a copy. Maybe just `yield {'number': j}`? You need to create newt objects if you want new objects.

Comment: As an aside, don't use list comprehensions for side-effects: `[print(x) for x in result]`

Comment: Haha - that will be my new motto **Dont use list comprehentions for side effects** 

I just went to read about it and I solved my problem by moving the obj into the loop. That way I removed the side-effect from the equation so to speak :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow ... you are using yield wrong ... why you use yield while saving in a list? ... you yield as the list and discard after that

```
def call(i):
    for j in range(i):
        yield j+1

def ring(i):
#you define obj here
    obj = {}
    for j in call(i):
        # if you want a different object each time instance here
        # or use obj[j] = j
        obj = {}
         
        obj['number'] = j
        # yield stop execution of this function and on next iteration continue from where it's left ... your return obj which is a reference to a dict
        yield obj
    
result = []
for k in ring(5):
    # print always puts \n after each call
    print(k) if k['number'] != 5 else print(f"{k} is 5",'\n')
    result.append(k)

[print(x) for x in result]

# - OUTPUT -
#
#{'number': 1}
#{'number': 2}
#{'number': 3}
#{'number': 4}
#{'number': 5} 
#
#{'number': 5}
#{'number': 5}
#{'number': 5}
#{'number': 5}
#{'number': 5}
```

I don't know if you know C, but simplified your code looks like this:

```
int* x = new int[10]
other* dict = new other
for (i=0;i<5;i++)
   dict.other = i
   x[i] = dict
```

while my code looks like:
int* x = new int[10]

```
for (i=0;i<5;i++)
   other* dict = new other
   dict.other = i
   x[i] = dict
```

Comment: Thank you. I know a little bit C, so I understand your example. This is first time I use yield for anything. But it also seem to me that I use it instead of appending to a list and returning the list. But maybe it has alot more to provide than I can imagine :) I will find out on my path of learning, and again thank you for the answer ! :)